# Using hierarchy to remove unwanted contours

Tags: java, c++, opencv, contour

My question is how I can access the parent value like I do in C++ in Java. In C++ I get an index of the matrix. In my C++ I do `if(hierarchy[i][4] == -1)`  That checks the parent value. When I try to do so in Java `hierarchy[i][4]` is a double array. So like `[2.0,1.3, 3.1, 0.5]` how can I access the last index of the double array of the matrix in Java?

In **C++** finding contours and checking hierarchy would be something like this

```
findContours( image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
// loop through the contours/hierarchy
    for ( int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++ ) {
        // look for hierarchy[i][3]!=-1, look at hierarchy index.
        if ( hierarchy[i][4] == -1 ) {
            //once this is true you can do whatever 
            Scalar colour( (rand()&255), (rand()&255), (rand()&255) );
            drawContours( outImage, contours, i, colour );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have my **Java** equivalent

```
//define hierarchy
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
//find contours
Imgproc.findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
double[] whatParentShouldBe = {-1.0}; //This doesn't do what I want it to.

//Remove iterate through contours 
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){

    double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)); 
    MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());

    double perimeter = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true);
    //Found squareness equation on wiki... 
    //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)
    double squareness = 4 * Math.PI * area / Math.pow(perimeter, 2);

    System.out.println("4:" + Arrays.toString(hierarchy.get(i, 4)));
    //This prints out something like [3.0,2.1,1.9,-1]    
    //I want to get the last index and of it see if it is -1 like the C++ example
    //Instead what it turns out I am doing is 'if [3.0,2.1,1.9,-1] == [-1.0]

    //add contour to new List if it has a square shape and no parent contours
    if(squareness >= 0.7 && squareness <= 0.9 && area >= 2000 && hierarchy.get(i, 4) == whatParentShouldBe){
       squareContours.add(contours.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to get the hierarchy parent the  it is done in C++. I check for  the `[i][4]` and see if it is equal to -1. It is a single value and not an array like in Java. How can I access the the last value in the hierarchy array in Java. @tobi303

Comment: updating the question. What I am looking for is the actually the reverse. C++ to Java. @Error-SyntacticalRemorse

Comment: just add a ? and add it to the question. Comments are overlooked easily and the question should be part of the question ;)

Comment: I have done most of the translation its just that I am not sure how I can access the the hierarchy parent index like I do in C++ in Java. I want to check the specific index @Error-SyntacticalRemorse

Comment: If all you want is external contours, then don't bother with hierarchy and use `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`. | If `hierarchy.get(i,4)` returns you an array with 4 elements, then just use indexing on that array to access the desired element and compare that with a single value... I'm no Java wizard, but I'd expect something like `hierarchy.get(i, 4)[3] == -1` to do the job.

Comment: thanks that helped. I didn't know I could do that @DanMašek